# Get back from select object to collection object

Tags: magento2, collection, select

If I do `$collection->getSelect()` I am moving from `collection` object to `select` object and I can use some useful stuff more close to raw sql.

But what can I do to get back from `select` to magento `collection`?
If, for example, I want to use `$collection->getFirstItem()->getId()`?

Comment: Can you share more detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$collection = your collection here;
$select = $collection->getSelect();
//do nasty stuff with the $select object.
```

since this is an object, it is passed by reference and anything you change in it will be reflected in the collection select

Then you can use again:

```
$collection->getFirstItem();
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't store the result of `getSelect()` into a new variable and try to call the collection methods on that new variable, you should still be able to use collection methods.

For example:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('is_enabled=?', 0);
return $collection->getFirstItem();
```

This would work perfectly fine.

Comment: it actually works even if you store the result of `getSelect` in a different variable. getSelect returns the select object associated to the collection. So your variable will be referencing the same select.

Comment: @Marius yeah the wording was not perfect, I edited my answer to be more understandable