# Add limit on collection of custom table and get one column value in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, query

I know there are solutions for getting one column as an array.

> $collection->getColumnValues('column_name');

And adding limit without `setPageSize()` and `setCurPage()`

> $collection->getSelect()->limit(3)

But I want both.

My temp solution is I'll run `foreach` loop over the collection from `limit` statement and just fetch the column in the array as per the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the below code which works fine for me.

```
$collection = $customObj->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('column_name');
$collection->getColumnValues('column_name');
$collection->getSelect()->limit(3);
echo '<pre>', print_r($collection->getData()); exit;

//Output : 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [custom_field_1] => Sample Text 1 for Data 1
        )

)
```

**As per your comment, I have updated my code which also working fine.**

```
$customData = [];
$collection = $customObj->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('column_name');
$collection->getSelect()->limit(3);
$customData = $collection->getColumnValues('column_name');
echo '<pre>', print_r($customData); exit;

//Output :

Array
(
    [0] => Sample Text 1 for Data 1
)
```

Comment: Yes, you are almost there, just need to interchange the sequence of the 2nd and 3rd statements and then assign the variable for the array for `getColumnValues` that will work. I've got a reference from this ans - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/145655/45519

Comment: Hi, As per your comment, I have incorporated your changes and updated my answer. If you find my answer useful then accept it, So it will help other community users.